# Is $(G \times N)/K$ open in $M$?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, lie-groups

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold on which acts a Lie group $G$. Let $N$ be a submanifold of $M$. Suppose that $K$ is a Lie subgroup of $G$ which acts on $N$.

Consider the  following action of  $K$ on $G \times N$:
$$k.(g,n):= (gk,k^{-1}n), \quad k \in K, (g,n) \in G \times N. $$

We can view the quotient space $(G \times N)/K$ as a subspace of  $M$ through the map $[(g,n)] \rightarrow g.n .$

Is the quotient space $(G \times N)/K$ an open set in $M$ ? I think it is, but I don't know how to prove that.

Comment: Isn't the image of this map simply $N$? Because each $g.n\in N$ (and so image is a subset of $N$) and $1.n=n$ (and so the map is surjective onto $N$).

Comment: We don't have an action of $G$ on $N$, we just have an action of $H$ on it.

Comment: I see. So the image of this map is equal to $GN=\{g.n\ |\ g\in G,n\in N\}$, right? In particular if $G$ acts on $N$, then $GN=N$ and thus it does not have to be open (you can find plenty counterexamples, e.g. $M=S^1$, $G=\mathbb{Z}_2$ acting by reflection and $N=\{-1,1\}$). Even when $G$ doesn't act on $N$ you can provide counterexamples (e.g. $M$, $G$ as earlier, $N=\{1\}$).

Comment: @freakish, Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me put into an answer what I wrote in comments. No, the image does not have to be open. In fact the image is equal to $GN=\{g.n\ |\ g\in G,\ n\in N\}$.

So take for example $M=S^1\subseteq\mathbb{C}$, $G=\{-1,1\}\simeq\mathbb{Z}_2$ acting on $M$ via reflections $(g,x)\mapsto gx$. Now take $N=\{1\}$ which is a $0$-dimensional submanifold of $M$. Then $GN=\{-1,1\}$ which clearly is not open.

In fact if $G$ is finite, $N$ is closed and $M$ connected then $GN$ is open only when $GN=M$. Which cannot happen for example when $\dim N<\dim M$ additionally.